# Using a dict to call functions from a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, key-value, dispatch

I would like the first two words of a user input string to be read as function arguments for where to save the string. I've settled on using a dict instead of many if statements, but I'm not sure how to structure the dict.

I believe this is a correct start:

input: "question physics What happens to atoms when they are hit by photons?"
result: *program saves the input in location questions\physics*

```
raw_entry = input("Enter text in the following format: type subtype text")
instructions = raw_entry.split()[:2]
```

The two words (each being a "get_id" in the example) will designate where to save the text. This example seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to change it for my case.

```
function_dict = {'get_id': 
                        (
                        # function
                        requests.get,

                        # tuple of arguments
                        (url + "/users/" + user,), 

                        # dict of keyword args
                        {'headers': self.headers}
                        )
                 }
```

Let me know if I'm going about this logically or if it doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put some example of raw_entry input.

Comment: ***Let me know if I'm going about this logically or if it doesn't make sense. Thanks!***:  I'll, asa I understand what you're trying to do, which is?

Comment: This is what I am assuming, base on the user input u want to execute different function/method?

Comment: @JamesSapam I added an example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define the functions separately from the dictionary

For example:

```
def get_id():
    ... the function's code ...

function_dict = { "get_id":get_id, ... }
```

you can then call the function with its keyword:

```
function_dict["get_id"]()
```

but you can also do this without a dictionary if the keyword is the same as the function name:

```
globals()["get_id"]()
```

Comment: Excellent, that's helpful. I was thinking (incorrectly) the function had to be inside the dict.

Comment: Couldn't OP leverage `partial` in their call like `partial(function_dict.get('get_id'), args)` ? That way argument passing still works as intended

Comment: Could be, but it depends on the function's signature (which the OP has no indication of at the moment).  If they're all defined with something like get_id(*params), then partial() may not be needed.  Fixed parameter injection would probably be better handled by lambdas directly in the dictionary.

Comment: @AlainT. I was going to use dict to json, but decided to just make a text file for each combination of type/subtype to keep it simple.